# clang: error: while accessing a library(contains kiss xml) in sub-project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, workspace, multiple-projects

We have a workspace with the below structure:

SampleProject1

SampleProject2    >>Sub-Project

---

Now, we are trying to access the *SampleProject1* in *Sub-Project.*  After setting the

*Header Search Path*

in *Sub-Project* able to access the *Sampleproject1*. But, the *SampleProject2* is showing build error as follows:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DDXMLDocument", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libMyervices.a(MyService.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In *SampleProject1*, we have integrated *KissXML*.

Thanks in advance